# How can I retrieve my youtube list of videos? My program just hangs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

For some reason the program hangs.
I'm using Google API v3.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Test {
    class RetrieveYoutubeVideosList {
        private static int MaximumResults = 0;

        public static void RetrieveUploads(int MaxResults) {
            try {
                MaximumResults = MaxResults;
                new RetrieveYoutubeVideosList().Run().Wait();
            } catch (AggregateException ex) {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        UserCredential credential;
        string errr = "";
        private async Task Run() {
            try {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\jason file\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                        // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
                    );
                }
            } catch(Exception err) {
                errr = err.ToString();
            }
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

            // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
            var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items) {
                // From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
                // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

                Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

                var nextPageToken = "";
                while (nextPageToken != null) {
                    var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = MaximumResults;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

                    // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                    var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                    foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items) {
                        // Print information about each video.
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                    }

                    nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In form1's constructor:

```
RetrieveYoutubeVideosList.RetrieveUploads(50);
```

I'm using a breakpoint. It gets to this line:

```
var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

But once I click continue nothing happens. The program just hangs until I stop it.

Comment: I found how to do it without using await.

Comment: Added this one to the issue 590 https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/590